# Nested SQL SELECT in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I'm looking for a way to generate the following SQL in Rails (to make it a scope), so that I could chain it with further [scopes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) (e.g. `Article.published.most_comments`):

```
SELECT *, cs.count
FROM articles, (
  SELECT article_id, count(*)
  FROM comments
  GROUP BY comments.article_id
) cs
WHERE articles.id = cs.article_id
ORDER BY cs.count DESC;
```

I've tried something along the lines of `Article.joins(:comments).select('*').group('comments.article_id')`, but that doesn't generate the desired SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM "articles"
INNER JOIN "comments" ON "comments"."article_id" = "articles"."id"
GROUP BY comments.article_id

(PSQL): PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "articles.id"
        must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in
        an aggregate function
```

And there doesn't appear to be a `.from` method in which I could specify the nested SQL SELECT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, there's a [.from method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-from):

```
scope :most_comments, -> {
  Article.select('*, cs.count').from(
    'articles, (
      SELECT article_id, count(*)
      FROM comments
      GROUP BY comments.article_id
      ) cs'
    )
    .where('articles.id = cs.article_id')
    .order('cs.count DESC')
}
```

Not sure if this is the best way but it works...